# Apresentar todas as tabelas na coluna de navegação do PHPMyAdmin

Tags: paginação, phpmyadmin

O [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> nestas últimas versões tem o número de tabelas na navegação lateral esquerda limitado, sendo aplicada uma paginação às mesmas.

[image: Ilustração do novo Layout da Navegação]

Não só tenho reparado ser algo mais lento como pouco prático em grandes bases de dados.
<sup>(opinião pessoal)</sup>

## Pergunta

Como desactivar a paginação na coluna lateral esquerda do PHPMyAdmin de forma a que todas as tabelas estejam presentes tal como em passadas versões ?

<sup>Se relevante, a versão em questão é [4.2.3](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*Obs: esta solução não desativa a paginação efetivamente, mas o resultado na prática é o mesmo.*

A resposta depende se você quer que as configurações sejam aplicadas sempre, ou somente na sessão atual.

### Para aplicar somente na sessão atual:

1. Vá para a página principal do phpMyAdmin (ícone da casinha)
2. Em "Appearance Settings", clique em "More Settings..."
3. Clique em "Navigation Panel"
4. Mude o número de itens em "Maximum items in
   branch" para um valor bem alto
5. Clique em "Save"

### Para aplicar sempre:

Neste caso é necessário alterar o mesmo parâmetro ("Maximum items in a branch"), mas em vez de configurar pela tela, editar o arquivo de configuração do phpMyAdmin (`config.inc.php`), trocando o valor padrão do parâmetro `$cfg['MaxNavigationItems']`.

Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados [neste link da documentação do phpMyAdmin](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxNavigationItems).